# Strange behavior of CreateProcess with bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-phone-8, cmd, system

I need to execute a bat file programmatically on windows phone 8 platform. 
Problem is that CreateProcess() does not give me any errors. Nor does the WaitForSingleObject(), it just passes through it without waiting, which in effect means that the batch file never executes(since it takes atleast 5 minutes for the bat file to complete the operation).
Here is the code I am using:

---

param = L"\"c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe\" /C \"C:\\Data\\test\\spec_run_dir\\runSpec.bat\" \".exe\" \"ref\"";

if (!CreateProcess(NULL,
        (LPWSTR)param.c_str(),
        NULL,
        NULL,
        FALSE,
        0,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        &si,
        &pi)
        )
    {
        return(str = GetLastError().ToString());
    }

dwEvent = WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

---

What am i doing wrong here? Can someone help? I am stuck with this for a long time now.

Comment: You cannot use CreateProcess() on a phone, it will not compile.  Whatever you are running is not this code.  The entire notion of running a .bat file that sucks the battery empty for 5 minutes is rather bizarre.

Comment: This code is not for app store but for benchmark purpose. So, its pretty normal.

Comment: For me CreateProcess works because I use a custom SDK. But, if you know any other way using windows phone SDK, let me know.

Comment: @HansPassant How can you vote it down without knowing a thing?

Comment: Erm, wait, there are thousands of SO users that could have voted.  Why do you assume it is me?  Just because I'm the only one that's been trying to help you?  I have to say, I too am very curious why you think you can use CreateProcess and your question doesn't give any insight whatsoever on how that might have happened.  Show us what you know, it is a two-way street.

Comment: The problem, FWIW, is probably that you forgot to encode the backslashes in the string.  It should be `c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe`.

Comment: You are right Harry. That needs to be done too along with the population of lpApplicationName param of CreateProcess() with "c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe". I will edit my answer above.

Comment: Minor point of order: you should consider moving your answer from the question to an answer and accept it.

Comment: @HansPassant CreateProcess is a part of partner-only SDK for Windows Phone, called RPAL. You will not find much documentation about this , unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I found the solution to it. lpApplicationName param of CreateProcess() has to be populated with "c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe" too. This works for me.